# Spring 4 + Hibernate 4 Integration. Tables are not automatically created

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

I started working with Spring a few days ago, and for some reason I just can't get Hibernate to automatically create table entities (I've used hibernate a few times in other projects, so I know it has this capability). How do I fix this? I'm attaching some code that may be helpful.

HibernateConfiguration.class

```
@Configuration
@EnableTransactionManagement
@ComponentScan("br.com.jeffersontpadua.spring.config")
@PropertySource(value = {"classpath:application.properties"})
public class HibernateConfiguration {
    @Autowired
    private Environment environment;

    @Bean
    public LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory() {
        LocalSessionFactoryBean sessionFactory = new LocalSessionFactoryBean();

        sessionFactory.setDataSource(dataSource());
        sessionFactory.setPackagesToScan("br.com.jeffersontpadua.spring.model");
        sessionFactory.setHibernateProperties(hibernateProperties());

        return sessionFactory;
    }

    @Bean
    public DriverManagerDataSource dataSource() {
        DriverManagerDataSource dataSource = new DriverManagerDataSource();

        dataSource.setDriverClassName(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.driverClassName"));
        dataSource.setUrl(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.url"));
        dataSource.setUsername(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.username"));
        dataSource.setPassword(environment.getRequiredProperty("jdbc.password"));

        return dataSource;
    }

    private Properties hibernateProperties() {
        Properties properties = new Properties();

        properties.put("hibernate.dialect", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.dialect"));
        properties.put("hibernate.show_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.show_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.format_sql", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.format_sql"));
        properties.put("hibernate.hbm2dll.auto", environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2dll.auto"));

        System.out.println("Hibernate config: " + environment.getRequiredProperty("hibernate.hbm2dll.auto"));

        return properties;
    }

    @Bean
    @Autowired
    public HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager(SessionFactory sessionFactory) {
        HibernateTransactionManager transactionManager = new HibernateTransactionManager();

        transactionManager.setSessionFactory(sessionFactory);

        return transactionManager;
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
jdbc.driverClassName = com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
jdbc.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/coaching_works
jdbc.username = root
jdbc.password = 1234
hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect
hibernate.format_sql = true
hibernate.show_sql = true
hibernate.hbm2dll.auto = update
```

Costumer.java

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "costumer")
public class Costumer {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue
    @Column(name = "id", nullable = false, updatable = false, unique = true)
    private int id;

    @Column(name = "full_name", nullable = false, length = 160)
    private String fullName;

    public int getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(int id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFullName() {
        return fullName;
    }

    public void setFullName(String fullName) {
        this.fullName = fullName;
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo: the property is called `hibernate.hbm2ddl.auto` (..ddl.. not ..dll..)

Comment: I can't believe that was the problem. Thank you very much for your help. Really appreciate it. o/